# Did Thorfinn care about Askeladd?

Tags: vinland-saga

At the end of *Vinland Saga* anime,

> when Thorfinn learns that Askeladd is dead, he becomes really frustrated and doesn't know what to do.

Was this just because he couldn't take his revenge or did he actually care about Askeladd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess he had some mixed feelings.

At the very least, we know that he didn't know how to live from that point onwards, he lost his trustees and became lonely. I don't think revenge and other base things were what made Thorfinn follow Askeladd.

Probably, Thorfinn really cared about him but the author didn't really dig deeper into his feelings.